# Cómo controlar recv socket para descartar datos sólo cuando haya send por parte del servidor TCP en python?

Tags: python, socket, tcp

veréis, es que estoy realizando un cliente en python y la cosa es que tengo que que recibir una serie de numeros y contarlos hasta que llegue al 0 (es decir, recibo hasta que llegue al 0). Pues los cuento y despues de eso pongo un recv para descartar los siguientes mensajes que van a seguir siendo secuencias de numeros. EL caso es que funciona y de esa forma después envío el contador que le tengo que enviar y funciona, pero cuando el último mensaje en recibir es el que contiene el 0, como después está el recv pues se queda esperando a recibir del servidor, pero en ese caso, como ha recibido todo, no debería de hacer ningún rrcv. Entonces mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer para que en el caso de que queden por recibir más secuencias de números reciba, pero en el caso que haya recibido todos que no haga un recv para quedarse en estado bloqueante y me envíe mis datos directamente.

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Si el servidor no te informa de alguna manera (numero de secuencias a recibir o usando una secuencia predeterminada para indicar que no va a enviar nada por ejemplo) lo único que te queda es poner un tiempo de espera máximo...